# Error uploading updates

Tags: ios, xcode

I am trying to upload my app's updates via Xcode to itunesconnect using this method:
1) Changed the version number from 1.0 to 1.01 on the target summary window.
2) Add the version number, 1.01 to iTunes connect
3) I then cleared build folder from Product -> Clean Build Folder
4) Product -> Build for -> Archiving
5) Product -> Archive
6) A 'Organiser - Archives' window pops up with with the latest archive i just did on the first row of all the archives i've done in the past, with options to 'Validate' or 'Distribute'. Trying to be on the safe side, i decide to 'Validate' to see if there's any error.
7) An error pop up with this message:

```
This bundle is invalid. The keyCFBundleVersion in the Info.plist must contain a higher version than that of the previously uploaded version.
```

Thinking that 1.01 is not acceptable, i changed it to 1.1 and followed steps 3 through 6 with the same error.

I then changed it to 1.10 and still followed the same step 3 through 6 with yet again the same error.

I finally changed it to 2.0 and still followed steps 3 through 6 with yet again the same error.
I checked the plist file and it reflects the changes i've made to the version number. I retried the whole sequence of version number from version 1.1 to 1.01 to 1.10 to 2.0 but i closed Xcode after every change then reopened thinking it has something to do with cached issues (if any) in Xcode with the same result.

I emailed apple support and they eventually replied (i understand that they're swarmed with emails on daily issue), asking me to use the Technical Support. Now i have 2 credits that i intend to use for other technical discussion over other issues.

I appreciate any pointers on this matter.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you changing this version?

[image]

This is the field it is complaining about.